# Express req.subdomains empty

Tags: node.js, express

I have this in the Windows `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       demo.app.com
```

And when I test it at `http://demo.app.com:5000/`, `req.subdomains` returns `["demo"]`.

However, when I deploy it to an Ubuntu server, the `req.subdomains` returns `[]`.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It's due to the nginx reverse proxy.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.app.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the solution?

Comment: The provided code doesn't fix it?